# How to use the same equivalent of REGEXP_REPLACE(Oracle sql) in edb

Tags: oracle, enterprisedb

I am migrating from oracle sql to edb and wanted to convert the regular expression replace, but i am not able to bring all the constraints to the edb equivalent. Could you please help.

```
SET account_no = RTRIM (LTRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE (account_no, '[A-Y]', '', 1, 0, 'i'), ' '), ' ')
```

How do i bring the position(1), occurrence(0) and match_parameter('i') in edb. If i use the same i am getting the below error

ERROR:  function regexp_replace(character varying, unknown, unknown, integer, integer, unknown) does not exist
LINE 2: SET customer = RTRIM (LTRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE (customer, '...
^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL's implementation of `regexp_replace()` is different from Oracle's.  The function signature [as mentioned in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) is `regexp_replace(source, pattern, replacement [, flags ])`

Calling `regexp_replace(account_no,'[A-Y]','','gi')` would be the equivalent of your desired invocation of `regexp_replace(account_no,'[A-Y]','',1,0,'i')`

Comment: Thank you. it worked and also thanks for the explanation.